# String literal with if

Tags: excel, string, formula, string-literals

Currently my formula is this:

```
=SUMIFS(G:G, $C:$C,"Architect")
```

Column G is a column of figures.

```
10.80
2.97
2
etc
```

Column C is a reference from another sheet.(job titles, "Architect", "Program Manager", "Engineer" or left blank)

```
='another_tab'!C1
='another_tab'!C2
='another_tab'!C3
etc
```

The formula should add up all costs for Architects. However, it doesn't work I suspect I've got a problem in Excel with string literals. The formula shows: 0

Replacing the text in column C (paste values) makes the formula work, so the problem how to get the SUMIFS to look for a string literal.

I thought TEXT would work, but with no success (using "general" text format code) I also tried using 'before the reference but that added to the confusion as the formula in C uses ' as part of the reference.

Is there a way I can adjust my formula to cope with string literals? No VBA!

Comment: 1. What does C:C show as values from the formulas on the worksheet? 2. Does `=SUMIFS(G:G, $C:$C,"*rchite*")` give any result? (correct or incorrect) 3. *'it doesn't work'* is not an error code nor an adequate description of the problem.

Comment: @Jeeped. I've edited the question. Currently the formula shows 0: =SUMIFS(G:G, $C:$C,"*rchite*") also shows 0

Comment: Does your sheet show the formula string or the result string? (i.e ='another_tab'!C3, or "Architect) I did a test where the result string was shown and it worked correctly. I used both SUMIF and SUMIFS.

Comment: assuming you have architect in C4.  in an empty cell enter `=LEN(C4)`.  Then count the number of letters in architect and see if is the same number as displayed in C4.  you may have a phantom space. and there are ways of dealing with that.  Also make sure you do not have any typos in the name in the formula.  I noted Jeeped asked for "*rhite*" and you answered with out using the * not sure if you tried with and with out the * in your formula.

Comment: in your c column you can also try cleaning up spaces and other hidden characters by placing the reference to the other sheet in side of `TRIM` and `CLEAN`.  ie. `=TRIM(CLEAN('Another_tab'!C1))`

Comment: Yup, that was it. Whitespace the hiding where you least expect it ;)

Comment: @Forwarded, if you want to Put the trim formula as a an answer I'll mark it as the correct solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data probably has hidden characters or extra spaces at the end which you are not seeing.  You can test for spaces by using the following formula to check your data.

```
=LEN(C1)-LEN(TRIM(CLEAN(C1)))
```

If you get 0 there are no hidden characters or extra spaces.  Anything other than 0 and you do have them.  you now have two choices.  Fix the data or wrap your cell references in TRIM(CLEAN(cell reference)).  ie:

```
=TRIM(CLEAN('Another_tab'!C1))
```